# Integrate by partial fraction decomposition

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{5x^2+9x+16}{(x+1)(x^2+2x+5)}dx$$
Here's what I have so far...
$$\frac{5x^2+9x+16}{(x+1)(x^2+2x+5)} = \frac{\mathrm A}{x+1}+\frac{\mathrm Bx+\mathrm C}{x^2+2x+5}\\$$
$$5x^2 + 9x + 16 = \mathrm A(x^2+2x+5) + (\mathrm Bx+\mathrm C)(x+1)=\\$$
$$\mathrm A(x^2+2x+5) + \mathrm B(x^2+x)+\mathrm C(x+1)=\\$$
$$(\mathrm A+\mathrm B)x^2 + (2\mathrm A + \mathrm B + \mathrm C)x + (5\mathrm A+\mathrm C)\\$$
$$\mathrm A=-3,\;\mathrm B=8,\;\mathrm C = 31$$
$$$$
$$\int\frac{5x^2+9x+16}{(x+1)(x^2+2x+5)}dx = \int\bigg(-\frac{3}{x+1}+\frac{8x+31}{x^2+2x+5}\bigg)dx\Rightarrow$$
$$\int-\frac{3}{x+1}dx +\int\frac{8}{x^2+2x+5}dx+\int\frac{31}{x^2+2x+5}dx $$

Hopefully I've got it correct until this point (if not, someone point it out please!). I can do the first integration by moving the -3 out and using $u=x+1$ to get 
$$-3 \ln(x+1)$$
but I'm stuck on the next two.

Comment: Is $2A+B+C=9$ for $A=-3,B=8,C=31$?. Doesn't seem right.

Comment: I was just looking at that, actually. Checking it out now.

Comment: Should be $A=3,B=2,C=1$.

Comment: Is the last coefficient not 5A + C = 16?

Comment: It is. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: The second integral seems to be missing a factor of $x$ which might help simplify things.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah nevermind, I messed up the sign of A which is where I started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be $A=3,B=2,C=1$ and you get:

$$\int \frac{3}{x+1} dx + \int \frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+5} dx -\int \frac{1}{x^2+2x+5}dx$$

The second is easy by using $u=x^2+2x+5$ and other answerers have covered the last.

The key is writing $\frac{2x+1}{x^2+2x+5} = \frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+5} - \frac{1}{x^2+2x+5}$.

It's probably easier to just set $u=x+1$ at the start. Then you get:

$$\int\frac{5(u-1)^2+9(u-1)+16}{u(u^2+4)}\,du=\int\frac{5u^2-u+12}{u(u^2+4)}dx$$

Then write:

$$\frac{5u^2-u+12}{u(u^2+4)} = \frac{A}{u} + \frac{Bu+C}{u^2+4}$$
Giving $$A=3,B=2,C=-1$$, and the integrals:

$$\int\left(\frac{3}{u} + \frac{2u}{u^2+4} - \frac{1}{u^2+4}\right)\,du$$

Comment: could you explain how you get the numerators in the second and 3rd integrals? I thought it was just $\int\frac{a}{...}+\int\frac{bx+c}{...}$ which turned into $\int\frac{a}{...}+\int\frac{bx}{...}+\int\frac{c}{...}$?

Comment: $2x+1$ can certainly be written as $2x+2-1$. It's easier to do the integral if you have $2x+2$ in the numerator, compared to $2x$, because the derivative of $x^2+2x+5$ is $2x+2$.

Answer (score 4):

**PS:**

Thomas Andrews says the values of $A,B,C$ are in error.  I haven't checked those, but the technique outlined below still works if different numbers are involved.

**end of PS**

$$
\int\frac{8x+31}{x^2+2x+5}\,dx
$$
First let $w=x^2+2x+5$ so that $dw=(2x+2)\,dx$.  Then we have
$$
\int\frac{8x+31}{x^2+2x+5}\,dx = 4\int\frac{2x+2}{x^2+2x+5}\,dx+ \int\frac{23\,dx}{x^2+2x+5}
$$
Use the substitution to handle the first integral. Then
$$
\overbrace{\int\frac{23\,dx}{x^2+2x+5} = \int\frac{23\,dx}{(x+1)^2+2^2}}^{\text{completing the square}} = \frac{23}2\int\frac{dx/2}{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2+1} = \frac{23}2 \int\frac{du}{u^2+1}
$$
and get an arctangent.

Comment: Not sure you know what PS means :)

Comment: "postscript", i.e. something written later.

Comment: an additional remark at the end of a letter, after the signature and introduced by “P.S.”

Comment: In a letter written on paper with a pen, it's necessarily at the end, but I don't think that's essential to the concept.  This is a different format. What is essential is that it's added later.

Comment: Yeah, I was mostly kidding, but I have *never* seen PS used for a preamble note. The term "post script" is used more generally for notes added later, but "PS" has always been at the end of the text.

Answer (score 2):

(Just working on the last integral, but not checking the partial fractions.)  Complete the square:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+2x+5} = \int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2 + 4}$$

Now, substitute $x+1 = 2\tan(t)$.  So, $dx = 2\sec^2 t\;dt$.  Thus:
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2 + 4} &= \int\frac{2\sec^2(t)dt}{4(\tan^2t + 1)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sec^2 t\; dt}{\sec^2t} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int 1\; dt\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: $\sin^2 t + 1\neq \cos^2 t$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Should be better now.  Thanks again.

Comment: what would this look like back in terms of x?

Comment: @Jessica Something along the lines of $\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)$.  (Just noticed another mistake--didn't cancel properly. doh.)